# Javascript dynamic importing specific function not the whole module

Tags: javascript, import

We have some large load modules and we only want to import a few functions.  I search online that we can dynamically import modules and also destructure them to get a specific function.

https://blog.alexdevero.com/dynamic-imports-javascript/

```
// File 1:
// Use default export to export a function:
export default (numA, numB) => numA * numB


// File 2:
// Create async function:
async function loadModule() {
  // Use dynamic import to import function from "file1"
  // and use destructuring assignment with alias:
  const { default: defaultExport } = await import('./file1')

  // Use the imported function by using the alias:
  defaultExport(315, 414)
}

// Call the loadModule() function:
loadModule()
// Output:
// 130410
```

In this example, it means that the whole load module is imported and not just the function, right ?

Currently, is there a way to import only the function dynamically ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load a specific function instead of the whole module, you need [Tree Shaking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tree_shaking)

*Tree Shaking* lets you load only the used parts of the module and eliminate the non-used elements. However, this does not happen automatically. You need to use a bundler (i.e., [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup)). The bundler examines your code statically, discards the unused parts, and outputs the bundled code. You use the bundled code.

On the other hand, dynamic imports are used for different purposes. It loads your module if only the `loadModule()` function is called on runtime.

```js
if (false) {
  // This code is never executed.
  // So the module is never imported.
  const myFunc = await import('./file1');
}
```

You can use both *Tree Shaking* and dynamic imports simultaneously for different purposes.

### Why is it impossible to load only Function A without a bundler?

Bundlers examine your whole code statically before running. Assume we only load *function A* from the module. What if the *function A* depends on *function B* from the same file? Without examining, we cannot know what code depends on another code from the same file. Bundlers do this examination.

Comment: So if module has function A,B,C, it's not possible to load only function A at run time ?

Comment: With a bundler, it is possible to load only function A. Without a bundler, it is not possible. Please read the reference in my answer for further information.

Comment: @EBDS, I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: thank for the explanation.  Actually, we are very sure that there is no dependencies.  But unfortunately, it cannot be done.  Thanks.

Comment: @EDBS. If you can't or don't want to use a bundler. You may consider to divide the module into multiple smaller modules by hand. For example, put "function A" into its own module. Not o good solution, but a solution...